# drive_find() or sheets_find doesn't get a shared google sheet in r

Tags: r, google-drive-api, googlesheets4

I am using googlesheets4 package in R. My colleague shared a google sheet with me with full access. But I cannot get it with either `drive_find()` or `sheets_find` but I do get other shared files. I don't know why.. Here's my code in R:

```
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)

drive_auth()
ss <- drive_get("DSI Style Tags - Class List") ## returns 0 obs
a <- drive_find(type = "spreadsheet")  ## returns all the spreadsheets in my drive or shared with me but the one I want
b <- sheets_find()  ## the same as drive_find, only the one i want is missing
```

How can I track the issue here? Many thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with `r`, but using the Goolge Drive API method [get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to access files on a shared drive as of now you need to set the option `supportsAllDrives` to `true`

Comment: @ziganotschka but I do get other files from other shared drives..

Comment: `Shared Drive` and `Shared with me` is not the same.  `supportsAllDrives` will become redundant by the end of JUne. But as of now it still isn't.

Comment: hi @ziganotschka yes i know it's not the same. I meant shared drives. i can get files from both shared and unshared drives. but just this one i cannot get it